# angular click event for element loaded via http request not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, ajax

codepen link : http://codepen.io/gauravcoder/pen/vLWEjJ?editors=101
i am new to angular js

i have items on click on which i put alert now, it works fine issue is that when item is loaded via http request click event does not works.

html code: (alert for first two non ajax items works only where as for other loaded via ajax call it does not works)

```
<ion-list>
    <div style="height:40px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc" id="clickit">
          Item No Ajax call
    </div>
    <div style="height:40px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc" id="clickit">
          Item No Ajax call
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" style="height:40px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc" id="clickit">
          Item Ajax Call: {{ item.username }}
    </div>

</ion-list>
<ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="10%"></ion-infinite-scroll>

</ion-content>
```

js code

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $("div#clickit").click(function() {
        alert('hey');
    });


    $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        $http.get('http://mourjewels.com/www/stones2.php?page='+$scope.currentPage).success(function(items) { 
            $scope.currentPage += 1;
            $scope.items = $scope.items.concat(items.data);
            console.log(items.count);
            $loopcount =  Math.ceil(items.count/10);
            console.log($loopcount);
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
            if($scope.currentPage >= $loopcount){
                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
                $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
            }
        });

      };

      $scope.items = [];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Angular executes your controller script before the AJAX loaded elements are injected to the DOM.

Anyway, in Angular there is definitely a different approach to this. You can use Angular's `ng-click` directive.

In your controller,

```
$scope.doSomething = function () {
    // Does something
};
```

In your HTML,

```
<div ng-click="doSomething()"></div>
```

Things like `ng-repeat`, `ng-click` are called [Directives](http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/) in Angular and are just custom extensions to the native DOM. `ng-` prefixed directives comes packed with Angular core. Everytime AngularJS updates the DOM, it collects the directives present in the DOM and executes the directives. So, in your case, `ng-repeat` and `ng-click` directives are executed. `ng-click` basically registers onclick DOM event handler to execute the given function (doSomething) on the current scope. So, it will work no matter how or when that DOM is injected.

Very simplified explanation of course. But I hope it makes sense to you :)

Comment: thanks for same can u tell if i write <img src="img/011.png" alt="top" ng-click="doSomething()"/> can i get clicked element src ?

Comment: sure, ng-click="doSomething($event)" in your HTML and $scope.doSomething = function (event) { // event.target is your element }

Comment: But, instead of having DOM logics in the controller, i would create a custom directive and handle the DOM there.

Comment: thanks for same can u tell refrence site where i can alternative to jquery event in angular js like next(); and other

Comment: next() is not an event. What exactly do you mean?